# Help on Non integrable equation ($\dot{x} = R\dot{\phi}\sin\theta$)

Tags: calculus, integration

This question is uses this post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744555/question-on-non-holonomic-constraintsthis-is-different-to-the-others?noredirect=1#744555), but I think the problem that I am having is that I am not understanding the integration part. $x,y,\theta,\phi$ are I assume functions of $t$, $R$ is $a$ constant.

Let the equation be:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\dot{x} = R\dot{\phi}\sin\theta \end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\frac{dx}{dt} = R\frac{d \phi}{dt}\sin\theta \end{equation}

Then they integrate both sides(I assume that we are integrating w.r.t $dt$?)
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\int\frac{dx}{dt}dt = R\int\sin\theta \frac{d \phi}{dt}dt
\end{equation}

I understand the LHS, but they do the RHS like:

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
x = R\int\sin\theta d\phi
\end{equation}
Question, From this it looks like the dt cancel out leaving our integral w.r.t $d\phi$ now. But we can't do the integration w.r.t $d\phi$ (where we let the $\theta$ be treated as a constant) to get:
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
x = R\sin\theta \int d\phi
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
x = R\sin\theta \phi
\end{equation}

But now this is incorrect as if we take the time derivative of the above equation
\begin{equation}\tag{7}
\frac{d}{dt}x = \frac{d}{dt}(R\sin\theta \phi)
\\
\dot{x} = R\frac{d}{dt}(\sin\theta)\phi +  R\sin\theta\dot{\phi} \neq R\dot{\phi}\sin\theta
\end{equation}

My question is where am I going wrong in my calculations? I would greatly appreciate if you could break it down for me as it appears that the integral can cancel out the "$dt$" then the integral uses "$d\phi$", but now we can't do this? I am so confused.

Answer (score 1):

This artistic use of Leibniz's $d$ notation seems wrong but it isn't. Physicists can do this, although rigorous proof of why it can be done is a bit troublesome.

It looks as if $\theta$ isn't depending on time. Let's go to equation three:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\int\frac{dx}{dt}dt = R\int\sin\theta \frac{d \phi}{dt}dt
\end{equation}
The next step would be
\begin{equation}\tag{3'}
\int dx = R\int\sin\theta d \phi=R\sin(\theta)\int d\phi
\end{equation}
and finally from that
\begin{equation}\tag{6'}
x = R \sin(\theta)\cdot \phi +C 
\end{equation}
Differentiation yields
\begin{align*}
\dot x(t)&= R\sin(\theta)\cdot \dot\phi(t)
\end{align*}
which is where we started at. This calculation works as long as $R$ and $\theta$ are time-independent constants.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. They say that equation 1 is not "integrable" but it looks like it can be integrated. Some thing is not so clear here.

Comment: I think the assumption that $R$ and $\theta$ are time-independent is wrong. Why should these two coordinates be constant while the other two, $x$ and $\phi$, are not? And if equation (1) would be $\dot x(t)=R(t)\cdot \dot\phi(t) \cdot \sin(\theta(t))$ then things are quite different and at least difficult to integrate by a closed form.